# Amplify Storage upload issue Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network Error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

```
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(config);
```

---

```
saveFile = async () => {
    const { file } = this.state
    await Storage.put(file.name, file)
    console.log('successfully saved file...')
  }
```

---

```
<input
  type="file"
  onChange={upload}
/>
```

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network Error
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/storage/lib-esm/providers/axios-http-handler.js/AxiosHttpHandler</AxiosHttpHandler.prototype.handle

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://zanjmob03dfe5b3e56e45e295a1a272470ca517233002-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/public/Screen%20Shot%202021-05-13%20at%201.01.43%20PM.png?x-id=PutObject. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

[ERROR] 06:08.429 axios-http-handler Error: Network Error

Answer (score 0):

I hope my comment helps someone who has the same issue and, like me, has come this far:

I encountered the same error and spent a while trying to figure out how to pass the headers or why I was getting this error stating that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header was not found in the request.

I realized that the credentials were incorrect due to a syntax error.
Make sure you are importing the configuration "Amplify.configure(awsconfig)". It's best to do it in App.tsx if you're not sure.

Additionally, check that the credentials in the object, in case you generated them manually like I did, are correct.
For example, verify that you have the correct bucket ID, identityPoolId, and region.

In my case, the awsconfig is an object like this:

```
const awsconfig = {
  Auth: {
    region: 'my region',
    userPoolId: 'my userPoolId',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'my userPoolWebClientId',
    identityPoolId: 'my identityPoolId'
  },
  Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: 'my bucket id',
      region: 'my region',
       identityPoolId: 'my identityPoolId'
    }
  }
}
```